# M.2 SSD Partitioning

Tags: ssd, m.2

I understand that very M.2 SSD is made of a few NAND chips. They are seen discrete on them by naked eyes.
Eg: a 256 SSD will have 4 Nos of 64GB NANDs.

If I chose to partition the M.2 SSD to a 128 one for OS and 2 64GB ones for other purposes, will they work as independent physical hard drives, like our good old Dard disks with rotating disks inside?

Comment: Yes, there's no difference.

Comment: They'll work exactly the same as **one** HD, partitioned, as far as the user experience is concerned. The only difference is speed.

Comment: Are you asking about NVMe namespaces or about "traditional" MBR/GPT partitions?

Answer (score 1):

Internal composition of SSD doesn't matter. Entire SSD is visible to the system as a single, continuous storage device. Separation into logical drives is provided only by partitioning.

Note that traditional HDDs also had multiple platters. They also didn't matter. It's drive's job to manage how it stores data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative: You may partition the SSD as you like, chip boundaries
are not important. The SSD remains one disk.

In the end, the disk has its channels to the motherboard which are used for
passing commands and data both ways, and the SSD firmware will handle requests
without caring about partition boundaries.